# How to call script.jsx to make react.js work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn react.js. I am trying to setup a little test environment but do not understand why my script.jsx is not working? Is there anything special you must do to the file? If I have everything on the same page is works properly like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="react-0.13.3.js"></script>
        <script src="JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>

        <script type="text/jsx">
          var Button = React.createClass({
            localHandleClick: function() {
              this.props.localHandleClick(this.props.increment);
            },
            render: function() {
              return (
                <button onClick={this.localHandleClick}>+{this.props.increment}</button>
              )
            }
          });

          var Result = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
              return (
                <div>{this.props.localCounter}</div>
              )
            }
          })

          var Main = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function() {
              return {counter: 0};
            },
            handleClick: function(increment) {
              this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+increment });
            },
            render: function() {
              return (
                <div>
                  <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={1} />
                  <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={5} />
                  <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={10} />
                  <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={100} />
                  <Result localCounter={this.state.counter} />
                </div>
              )
            }
          })

          React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
        </script>

      </body>

    </html>
```

But when I try to have an index.html file and a script.jsx file I cannot get it to run: like this:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="react-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script src="JSXTransformer-0.13.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/jsx" src="script.jsx"></script>

  </body>

</html>
```

**script.jsx**

```
var Button = React.createClass({
  localHandleClick: function() {
    this.props.localHandleClick(this.props.increment);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.localHandleClick}>+{this.props.increment}</button>
    )
  }
});

var Result = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>{this.props.localCounter}</div>
    )
  }
})

var Main = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {counter: 0};
  },
  handleClick: function(increment) {
    this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter+increment });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={1} />
        <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={5} />
        <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={10} />
        <Button localHandleClick={this.handleClick} increment={100} />
        <Result localCounter={this.state.counter} />
      </div>
    )
  }
})

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In the console it says this:

```
You are using the in-browser JSX transformer. Be sure to precompile your JSX for production - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tooling-integration.html#jsx
```

And

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/davidb/Desktop/TestReact/script.jsx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Will someone please tell me what I must do in order to get this to work properly instead of getting this stupid white screen.

Comment: https://fb.me/ were the actual links but it would not let me post them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not running a server.  In your browser, you are using the `file://` protocol. Browsers like Chrome do not allow you to load a file via `XMLHttpRequest` when using the `file://` protocol.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/davidb/Desktop/TestReact/script.jsx. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Instead, start a server on `localhost` and your code should work.

It looks like you are running Windows.  One way to set up a local server is via http://www.wampserver.com/en/

If you are running Mac, you can do something like:

```
cd ~/path/to/your/project
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
open http://localhost:8000
```